# Place map with transparent bg over another one

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to place one map over another so that I can make one "satellite view" map dark without affecting the color of roads and labels.
I want it to look like this:
http://pixfx.at/#Map

So I took some of their code and made it look like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#map {
height:543px !important;
background-image:url(../images/background_gradient_transparent.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
border-bottom:1px solid #666666;
margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;
overflow:hidden !important;
}

#map_canvas {
height:543px !important;
background-color:transparent !important;
overflow:hidden !important;
}

#map_canvas .terms-of-use-link {
display:none;
}

</style>




<script type="text/javascript">



    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(47.254072, 11.445657), 13);

    map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
    /*
    map.removeMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);
    map.removeMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
    map.removeMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
    map.removeMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);
    */
    //map.getDragObject().setDraggableCursor("move");
    map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
    map.enableContinuousZoom();
    map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
    map.enableDragging();

    }

    function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);




    jQuery('#map_canvas > div > div > div > div').each( function () {

        if(jQuery(this).css('zIndex') == '0')
        {
            jQuery(this).find('img').each( function() {
                jQuery(this).css({ opacity: '0.25' });
            });
        }

    });

    jQuery('#map_canvas > .gmnoprint').css({ display: 'none' });


            }

            window.onload = loadScript;
            </script>

            </head>



            <body>



            <div id="map">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
            </div>
```

Though the problem is that the map doesn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you supplied is invalid.

```
map.enableDragging();

} //<-- this bracket is unmatched

function loadScript() {
```

Also, this line : `var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));`
 use an unknown item. Wrong API usage/lacking a link?

As for your CSS, using custom pictures for both canvas, I see that #map_canvas is over #map, correctly.

Your problem lies within your javascript : you are not using the google map API correctly. I somewhat changed your code but GMap2 is still not defined...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(47.254072, 11.445657), 13);
        map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
        map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
        map.enableContinuousZoom();
        map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
        map.enableDragging();

        jQuery('#map_canvas > div > div > div > div').each( function () {
            if(jQuery(this).css('zIndex') == '0')
            {
                jQuery(this).find('img').each( function() {
                    jQuery(this).css({ opacity: '0.25' });
                });
            }
        });
        jQuery('#map_canvas > .gmnoprint').css({ display: 'none' });
    });
            </script>
```

Since Google Map API v2 is **deprecated** you should switch to version 3.

Also, you need to [Sign up for a Google Maps API key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html). Otherwise Google blocks you.

Go [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) and follow the instructions. :)

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I definitely want to port this to v3. If I do this in v3, how would I place one over the other? Do I have to create 2 maps (var map1, map2)?

Comment: No idea, but probably (and then modify the opacity of the one on top), good luck!

Comment: @pafAmuf I think the hybrid map type set in the following line `map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);` will do the trick for you *(placing one map over the other)*. I guess there would be something similar in V3. But it could mean that you would have to tweak the JQuery code if the Google maps HTML layout has changed since V2.

Comment: @Kraz: Version 3 of the Gmaps API no longer requires the use of API keys, or so the docs seem to suggest.