# Transparent parts on a satellite map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[I noticed this website](http://pixfx.at/) has two maps overlaying one another. They have a darkened satellite map overlaid with a normal map with transparent bits where there aren't any roads. I want to do this, but in V3.

I've searched all over google but I had no results.

I tried reverse engineering the website to no luck. What my question is, is how I can make parts of a map transparent so that I can see the satellite map behind it - without killing any visibility of the roads? Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: [Place map with transparent bg over another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664693/place-map-with-transparent-bg-over-another-one)

Comment: IMO the answer remains fundamentally the same. In addition, you're linking to a commercial website from both questions (rather than describing what you want in the question in more detail).

Answer (score 1):

The API v3 way to do this -- with `StyledMapType` and a `MapStyle` array -- is described in some detail in the documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps

The example they use is essentially the same as the website you've linked to; it changes the background of 'built up' areas, while leaving the roads and labels the same:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple.html

Note that this is a 'live' example (click 'map' to turn off the styling).

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that but noticed that it only supports hue, lightness and so on - but doesn't include opacity.